# Naive Estimator after Propensity Score Matching

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, treatment-effect

I wanted to compute a Naive Estimator after a Propensity Score Matching with full matching.

I came up with this code but I'm not sure.

How can I compute the ATT using a Native Estimator after PSM?

````r
library("MatchIt")
data("lalonde")

m.out2 <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + 
                    nodegree + re74 + re75, 
                  data = lalonde,
                  method = "full", 
                  distance = "glm", 
                  link = "probit")

m.data2 <- match.data(m.out2)

te <- weighted.mean(m.data2$re78[m.data2$treat],
                    m.data2$weights[m.data2$treat])
nte <- weighted.mean(m.data2$re78[!m.data2$treat],
                     m.data2$weights[!m.data2$treat])
ne2w <- round(te-nte, 2)

print(paste0("The ATT estimated with a NE is: ", ne2w))
```
````

Comment: That is all explained in the vignette on [Estimating Effects after Matching](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html) in `MatchIt`. A weighted regression of the outcome on the treatment with the matching weights supplied is the weighted difference in means.

Comment: @Noah you are right about regressions and weighted means ... my code was wrong :) thank you so much. Thanks for the reference

Comment: @Noah: would you please care to make this a quick answer?